# Is there something called the stagnation volume?

Tags: thermodynamics

When discussing the stagnation flow properties we always discuss stagnation temperature, stagnation pressure, and stagnation enthalpy. Is there also a stagnation property called the stagnation volume i.e. the volume the fluid occupies when the fluid in the flow is brought to stagnation isentropically?

Answer (score 1):

Stagnation volume is nothing but when the volume of a given gas or fluid has achieved a static condition. In case of stagnation the given mass achieves a state of constant zero or negligible velocity for practical cases. The entire kinetic energy energy is converted into potential energy. The pressure state can be any but its velocity must be zero.
For a more detailed analysis please refer to the attached link :

https://nptel.ac.in/courses/101103004/module4/lec3/1.html

Comment: Thank you for the notes. There is no 'minor heat loss' as stagnation properties are calculated assuming an isentropic process.

Comment: Oh yes ! I am sorry. It's an adiabatic process.

Comment: A reversible adiabatic process to be exact.